# Expressing “huh” tag?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, words, nuances, expressions

How would you express this type of tag?

For example:

> Lovers, huh? That’s what you think they are?

Would って work?

> 恋人って？そうと思う？

Comment: 「恋人か」とか「恋人ね」とか……。

Comment: Here (and in most cases), the って is more like "you say" than a "huh". Here, I would go with @AeonAkechi 's example and use か

Comment: A variety of ways to say huh.  https://jisho.org/search/huh